# Select inside multiple interations

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to build this object:

```
[
    {
        "color" : "red",
        "category" : "tshirts",
        "Items" : [
            {
                "r" : 1,
                "n" : "name: E624E",
                "s" : 9819217.000
            }, {
                "r" : 2,
                "n" : "name: 00F37",
                "s" : 9791564.000
            }, {
                "r" : 3,
                "n" : "name: 75B02",
                "s" : 9790543.000
            }, {
                "r" : 4,
                "n" : "name: 08864",
                "s" : 9485392.000
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "color" : "red",
        "category" : "shoes",
        "Items" : [
            {
                "r" : 1,
                "n" : "name: 20272",
                "s" : 9949541.000
            }, {
                "r" : 2,
                "n" : "name: 1E496",
                "s" : 9926730.000
            }, {
                "r" : 3,
                "n" : "name: 00F37",
                "s" : 9926493.000
            }, {
                "r" : 4,
                "n" : "name: 48A44",
                "s" : 9923929.000
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The way I'm building this is using Linq, iterating through a collection of Colors and Category:

```
var colors = ctx.Colors.Select(x => x.Color).Distinct().ToList();

foreach (var color in colors)
{
    var categories = ctx.Categories.Where(x => x.Color == color).Select(x => x.Category).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (var cat in categories)
    {
        List<ItemAttribute> iattr = (from i in ctx.Item
                                     where i.Color == color && i.Category == cat
                                     select new ItemAttribute { 
                                          r = i.R,
                                          n = i.N,
                                          s = i.S
                                      }).ToList();
        this.ItemStuff.Add(iattr);
    }
}
```

This works, and I get the desired outcome, but performance stinks and seems verbose.

Can anyone provide some insight into improving this?

Comment: It's LINQ to Entities, isn't it?

Comment: Your sample code doesn't make a lot of sense. You're selecting `Color` from `Category`? also the result would just be something like a `List<List<ItemAttribute>>`. Please show us a bit more of the real code.

Comment: ah...you're right, i was simplying the code and renaming entities, just updated it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
var results = 
    from i in ctx.Items
    group i by new { i.Color, i.Category } into g
    select new ItemGroup
    {
        color = g.Key.Color,
        category = g.Key.Category
        items =
            (from i in g 
             select new ItemAttribute
             { 
                 r = i.R,
                 n = i.N,
                 s = i.S
             })
            .ToArray()
    };
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var results = ctx.Items
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.Color, i.Category })
    .Select(g => new ItemGroup
    {
        color = g.Key.Color,
        category = g.Key.Category
        items = g.Select(i => new ItemAttribute
                { 
                    r = i.R,
                    n = i.N,
                    s = i.S
                })
                .ToArray()
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code follows the same suboptimal pattern in several places: rather than taking everything and grouping by color or category, you deal with a single color or a single category at a time. You do that in the outer loop when you iterate through `colors`, and then you do the same in the nested loop when you iterate `categories`.

This goes to `ctx` multiple times, each time with a separate query. In with rare exceptions, querying in a loop is a sure way to kill your performance. It is better to get everything, group by color/category, and then build the results the way you need.

Here is one way to do it:

```
var items = ctx.Item.Select(i => new ItemAttribute { 
    r = i.R
,   n = i.N
,   s = i.S
})
.GroupBy(i => new { i.Color, i.Category })
.OrderBy(p => p.Key.Color)
.ThenBy(p => p.Key.Category);
```

At this point you have groups of all items grouped by color and category, retrieved in a single query. What's left now is iterating the groups, and adding the data to the structure that you are populating.

Comment: Understood, I knew performance sucked because of the separate queries, and that working with a full-set was the fix, but just didn't know how.  But now I do thanks to your help.  Thank you!